# Accessing a Non-executable File in Windows by Adding It to PATH

Tags: windows, path

Let's say I have a folder called `C:\docs`, and in that folder I have a file called `stuff.txt`. I want to add the folder to my system's PATH in Windows, and be able to access the file with the following command, *without being in the same folder as the file*:

`C:\[some_folder_other_than_docs]>notepad stuff.txt`

How can I do this?

Comment: You can't.  That's not how it works.

Comment: That's not how the PATH works. The PATH is a search path for finding executables, not text files or documents or other files. For future reference, this site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS use. This type of question belongs on [su] instead. The [help] has more information if you need it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did not realize PATH couldn't find non-executables, but now I know.

Also, I did not realize this belonged in Super User. Whoops.